# What is the size of the particles which make axis of rotation in a rotating object?

Tags: kinematics, rotational-dynamics, rotation

In a rotating object some particles which are not moving tend to be in a straight line "axis of rotation" and all the other particles of the object tend to be in circular motion around the axis.I want to know how small those particles are which make the axis of rotation ?

Comment: -1, Not clear what you are asking.

Comment: The axis is not a physical thing. There are no particles associated with it.

Comment: @Floris then what are point particles ,do they not make the axis of rotation?

Comment: A point particle is a "mythical thing" which has mass but no size - used in physics to simplify analysis of collisions and things like that. There is no need to invoke them to talk about an axis of rotation - because the axis is a (mathematical) line in space, not made of matter. An axle (thing that holds the wheels of a car) is a mechanical object; an axis is mathematical.

Comment: if it is an abstract object then what is its significance defining the motion of a real object .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume there is no stick/pole/pivot for object to rotate around, as this creates a hole with no particle in that region.

So spin the object up like throwing a frisbee. When you say particles, I assume you mean molecules. It would seem to me, that unless the force from the outer rotating molecules balanced out exactly, which is extremely unlikely, the molecules in the centre would also rotate, they would be dragged around by unbalanced electrostatic forces,

More importantly,  they would probably naturally rotate because of the temperature of the object, it other words they are molecules that would rotate whether they were isolated or part of a rotating object.

[image]

This is an example of naturally occuring molecular rotational motion, up to a certain temperature  limit, the molecule will store energy as rotation.

The size of the particles at the centre of rotation depends on the material the object is composed of, as this leads to different molecular sizes.

Comment: so you are saying that there is nothing like axis of rotation in physics .

Comment: @Remy An axis of rotation is not necessarily a physical object. It is a line, about which the whole things rotates. A spinning donut spins around an imaginary line through it's hole.

Comment: @Steeven particles that are at axis of rotation do they rotate ?

Comment: @Remy Well, are the stuck to the rest of the object? Then yes...